# John Resig's JavaScript inheritance implementation: why `initializing`?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I am studying John Resig's [OOO implementations in JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). The code is like:

```
(function(){
    var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
    this.Class = function(){};
    Class.extend = function(prop) {
        var _super = this.prototype;
        initializing = true;
        var prototype = new this();
        initializing = false;
        for (var name in prop) {
            // ...
        }
        function Class() {
            if ( !initializing && this.init )
                this.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        Class.prototype = prototype;
        Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
        Class.extend = arguments.callee;
        return Class;
    };
})();
```

The problem is: **why we use `initializing` here?**

I guess that the statement `var prototype = new this();` may be async. So when the `new ChildClass()` is called, the initialization (assignment of the `properties` to the prototype of `ChildClass`) may not have been done. But I am pretty not sure whether it is correct or not.

After searching around, I still cannot understand the purpose of using the variable `initializing`. I found this article has some explanations, but I could not understand: [Understanding John Resig's 'Simple JavaScript Inheritance'](http://blog.buymeasoda.com/understanding-john-resigs-simple-javascript-i)

Could anybody explain the purpose of it in detailed? Say, give some scenarios where the code fails without the `initializing`?

---

#### Update

Problem solved.

I composed an article to record down the details: [Understanding John Resig’s ‘Simple JavaScript Inheritance’](http://biogpu.ddns.comp.nus.edu.sg/shaojiang-blog/understanding-john-resigs-simple-javascript-inheritance/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Class() {
    if ( !initializing && this.init )
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

when `initializing` is true then you are 'setting up' the Class object itself, so you don't want to call the `init` instance method defined by each concrete class.

You may do something like this:
    var RedCoupe = Class.extend({
        init: function () {
            this._type = 'coupe';
            this._color = 'red';
    });
    var myCar = new RedCoupe();

In this case, you want `new RedCoupe();` to call init, but not when defiing `var RedCoupe = Class.extend({ ... });`, does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks. Normally, when `Class.extend` is executed, the `initializing` is set to `true`, then the `new`, then set to `false`. If the `new` is always sync, when it reaches `if ( !initializing && this.init )`, the value is `initializing` is always `false`. If it is always `false`, why use it?

Comment: yes, sorry I've kinda said the opposite. so when initializing is true, it means  "setting up" the Class object, which `new this()` is assigned to the prototype of the Class, so we shouldn't call the `init` instance method.

Comment: edited the original post as you pointed out the typo, thanks~

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. But my question is: normally the `initializing` is always `false` when the statement `if ( !initializing && this.init )` is called, am I right? If always `false`, why use it?

Comment: ooo for "why use it", you will do something like this:

`var RedCoupe = Class.extend({ init: function () { this._type = 'coupe'; this._color = 'red'; }); var myCar = new RedCoupe();` 

In this case, you do want `new RedCoupe()`; to call init, but not when defiing `RedCoupe = Class.extend({ ... });`, does it make sense?

Comment: added more details to the answer

Comment: I `console.log` the execution sequence. When the code `RedCoupe = Class.extend({ ... });` is executing, it is calling the `init` function of its parent class, i.e., `Class` (through `new this()`), not the `init` function of `RedCoupe`. The `init` function is called when `new RedCoupe()`.

Comment: Oh, I suddenly understand what you mean. Yes, it does makes sense. Thanks very much! I would suggest your updating the answer to illustrate it more clearly for others' reference.

Comment: glad that helped. While it's great to learn fundamental JS, in case if you are not aware, ES6 has some native OO support (http://es6-features.org)
Although it's not yet fully supported by all browsers, many people use transpilers like babel (https://babeljs.io/) to transpile it to ES5 for now.